# C++ compiler that supports C++0x features?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is where any C++ compiler that supports C++0x features already?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both the 2008 Visual C++ 'Feature Pack' and g++ support some features.

The [list of C++0x features supported by g++](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

---

[The Visual C++ 2008 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=d466226b-8dab-445f-a7b4-448b326c48e7&displaylang=en) ...  includes an implementation of TR1. Portions of TR1 are scheduled for adoption in the upcoming C++0x standard as the first major addition to the ISO 2003 standard C++ library. Our implementation includes a number of important features such as:

- Smart pointers
- Regular expression parsing
- New containers (tuple, array, unordered set, etc)
- Sophisticated random number generators
- Polymorphic function wrappers
- Type traits
- And more!

Comment: I'm pretty sure VS2008 doesn't support any C++0x features. do you have any references for that?

Comment: You made that comment the same minute I added the link.

Answer (score 10):

GCC has some of it supported.
See [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Answer (score 8):

Microsoft's Visual Studio 2010 CTP (Community Technology Preview) contains support for [four C++0x features](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx) namely lambdas, auto, static_assert, and rvalue references.

You can download the VPC image [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=922b4655-93d0-4476-bda4-94cf5f8d4814&displaylang=en), make sure to read the bit about accounting for the January 1 2009 expiry date ([this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/briankel/archive/2008/10/27/visual-studio-2010-ctp-vpc-dealing-with-activation-messages.aspx) is referenced).

Comment: Anyone mentioning anything other than g++ gets downvoted by fanboys. Compare my post vs Andy's - both have same link, but also mention VC++, so get down votes.

Comment: @Pete: Thanks I wasn't sure if I had got something incorrect.  I thought I'd add a reference to VS2010 since no one else had yet mentioned it.  Irrelevantly I do also use g++ as when on linux - surely there is enough room for both especially when answering questions.

Answer (score 6):

- GCC 4.4 (not released yet) would support some features like auto.
- GCC 4.3 has not bad tr1 support and some feature like Variadic templates.
- Latest Intel compiler supports quite well some C++0x features: it already has support of auto and lambda function.

Comment: 4.2 has complete tr1 support,  I believe the 4.1 and 4.0 do as well.

Comment: Not really, even 4.3 has "regex" support and you can even compile
but regex_match always returns false... it is in GCC to do list. I think in 4.4 dev. branch this should be ok.

Answer (score 4):

There are compilers that partially support C++0x, but there can't be full support yet because the final C++0x has not yet been standardized.

Answer (score 4):

Scott Meyers has a nice detailed summary of C++0x support across some common compilers here:

http://www.aristeia.com/C++0x/C++0xFeatureAvailability.htm