# Compiler support for upcoming C++0x

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a compiler that has good support for the new C++0x?

I use GCC but unfortunately the current version 4.4 has a poor support for the new features.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657511/c-compiler-that-supports-c0x-features

Comment: Any so-called duplicate question that doesn't feature Comeau (or any EDG-based compiler, e.g., Intel; I'm not picky) as an answer is not worth linking to. :-P

Comment: @Chris, whether a question is a duplicate has nothing to do with its answers. If you think the answers to the other question are lacking, you can fix it by adding your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only compiler that has an implementation of concepts is conceptgcc (and even that is incomplete - but it is good enough to get a good feel for the feature).
Visual C++ 2010 Beta has some useful C++0x support - you can play with lambdas, rvalue references, auto, decltype.
Comeau C++ or the EDG based compilers are surprisingly not as advanced I would have expected them to be in their implementation of C++0x.
GCC 4.4 (variadic templates, initializer lists, inline namespaces, autor, decltype) probably has the most features implemented out of any of the other compilers, but is lagging in concepts and lambdas (separate branch development is ongoing).

Comment: conceptgcc only implements an outdated concepts proposal and is very buggy and unstable.

Comment: I thought concepts were removed from C++0x.

Answer (score 28):

The Apache Standard C++ Library project maintains [a wiki page of major compilers' C++0x support](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport).

Here are links to the vendors' pages describing their C++0x support:

- [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)
- [CodeGear C++Builder 2009](https://web.archive.org/web/20120715135311/http://docs.codegear.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/whatsnewtiburon_xml.html#432B2B4275696C6465722032303039)
- [Intel C++ Compiler](http://www.intel.com/software/products/compilers/docs/clin/main_cls/copts/ccpp_options/option_std.htm)
- Visual C++ 2009 and 2010 - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/146381/visual-studio-support-for-new-c-c-standards), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/dd465215%28v=vs.100%29?redirectedfrom=MSDN), or [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160127230241/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx)
- [Comeau C++](https://web.archive.org/web/20190108062108/http://www.comeaucomputing.com:80/43101features.html)

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid gcc is probably the best you're going to get at this stage.

There's a list of features and supported compilers here:

http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport

Comment: gcc may be the best free one. But the Comeau compiler has always been good.

Answer (score 3):

The current [beta version](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/43101features.html) of the [Comeau compiler](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/) seems to have good C++0x support.

Comment: I have tried http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/ the online compiler... and it wouldn't compile `std::shared_ptr`...

Comment: @Stephane: It's `std::tr1::shared_ptr`, not `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: I do believe that they have moved shared_ptr from tr1 namespace to the std namespace in C++ 0x or C++ 11 ... but chances are, I only had some strange dreams :)

Answer (score 3):

GCC 4.4 does at least have some of the cool features (`auto`, variadic templates, rvalue references, etc.). There are also development branches for concepts and lambdas.

See [C++0x support in GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html).

Answer (score 3):

Scott Meyers has a nice and detailed comparison here:

http://www.aristeia.com/C++0x/C++0xFeatureAvailability.htm

Answer (score 3):

GCC 4.6, released 3/25/11, supports [most of the non-concurrency-related features of C++0x](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.6/cxx0x_status.html). Now that C++0x is [no longer in flux](http://herbsutter.com/2011/03/25/we-have-fdis-trip-report-march-2011-c-standards-meeting/) compiler support may progress a little more quickly.

Answer (score 1):

C++0x is still not ready, so don't expect to have it supported atm. GCC 4.4 and [Visual C++ 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010/default.mspx) are good candidates (they have some of the most anticipated new feautres like lambdas and auto) that get you started, but the standard isn't finished yet.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend intel compiler if your on linux/unix it's got better support than GCC and produces faster/smaller binaries (I normally get a free 10% performance boost using it)

Comment: Update 12/12/12: The Intel Compiler support for C++11 is a nightmare on Windows.  It doesn't support initializer lists, override, final and  support for noexcept has just been added.  I've had internal compiler errors when compiling strict C++11 code with it.  We have a new C++11 project and gcc 4.7.2 is handling it well and productivity++ but getting a C++11 environment set up on Windows is next to impossible.