# C++0x Peer Constructor in VC2010

Tags: c++, constructor, c++11

According to the [C++0x spec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B0x#Object_construction_improvement), the following is legal

```
class A {
    A(int i) : x(i) {}
    A() : A(0) {}
    int x;
};
```

But it fails to compile (`"A" is not a nonstatic data member or base class of class "A"`) in VC 2010. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Perhaps you haven't specified c++0x in your compiler settings.

Comment: That's not the C++0x spec.  The C++0x spec is still in draft and awaiting approval, and looks nothing like wikipedia.  Here is the "Final Committee Draft": http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual C++ 2010 (also known as VC++ 10.0) as of this writing does not support delegating constructors, which is what your code snippet requires. VC++ 10.0 only has partial support for C++0x, and as of this writing, no compiler has implemented the entire C++0x feature set (although that will change soon, especially once the C++0x standard is finalized).

Scott Meyers have [a summary of C++0x support in gcc and MSVC compilers](http://www.aristeia.com/C++0x/C++0xFeatureAvailability.htm). Here's another list of [C++0x feature support in different compilers](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport). Also, [a list of C++0x features supported in Visual C++ 2010 straight from the horse's mouth](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx).

For now, initialize all members directly in the initialization list of your constructors:

```
class A
{ 
public:
    A(int i) : x(i) {} 
    A() : x(0) {} 
private:
    int x; 
};
```

Comment: @jameszhao00: It "works" because that's not a delegating constructor. You're creating an unnamed temporary `A` which will be destructed once the constructor finishes, which is not what you want.

Comment: Good point! Thank you for that clarification. Too used to Java/C# I guess :(

Comment: [Compiler support for upcoming C++0x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980573/compiler-support-for-upcoming-c0x/980621#980621)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio doesn't support all of 0x yet. (And nobody should be expected to; 0x isn't finalized.)

[This describes what 0x features are implemented in VS 2010.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465215.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

MSVC++ 2010 doesn't have support for [delegating constructor](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n1986.pdf)

[This page](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) lists C+ 0x features and their support in popular compilers.