# Is C++0x officialy released? do major compilers support it?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not sure if release is the right word, as it's not software, but a standard.
What I mean is, is the C++0x standard finished? is it still under development?
Do major compilers support it? partially, completely?

Answer (score 17):

> is the C++0x standard finished?

Yes!  It is finished.

<s>No.</s>

> is it still under development?

C++ is still under active development, but C++11 is not.

<s>Yes and no.  A Final Committee Draft (FCD) was issued last year.  No new features can be added to C++0x at this point; all of the changes at this point are either minor changes or changes required to resolve defects (sometimes the changes required to resolve defects are quite extensive).</s>

In March when the C++ Committee meets in Madrid there should be a vote to submit a Final Draft International Standard (FDIS).  If that vote succeeds, C++0x will be "finished," and this document will be submitted to ISO for ratification (or approval or whatever ISO calls the process).

If that vote fails or if the committee decides the document still isn't ready, then we'll have to wait until the next meeting and we'll see what happens.  Most of the blog posts from committee members have been positive about finishing in March, though

> Do major compilers support it? partially, completely?

Most major compilers have partial support for various C++11 features.  The [C++11 tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b11/info) here on Stack Overflow has a list of links to the latest draft of the Standard and to the documentation for several major compiler implementations with lists of which features are supported and which are not.  The Apache Stdcxx Wiki has what is probably [the best feature implementation status table](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C++0xCompilerSupport) available.

Comment: @Jared:  C++0x is a colloquial name, not an official name.

Comment: Also '0x' is more C/C++ like and '1x' is meaningless, pun-wise.

Comment: @Jared: I would bet that'll become C++11 if it makes it, and we'll see a C++1x emerge for the next standard. Stroustrup explicitly precised that this time he would prefer if the next standard were to come after only 5 years, to keep pace with the industry.

Comment: @Jared I think it was unofficially named that because no one knew when it was going to ve finished; you would say the same thing is it was 2009 and it was called C++1x; x being an unknown

Answer (score 4):

C++0x is not standardized yet, but is in final stages of standardization.

And compilers are implementing C++0x features. Visual C++ and GCC 4.x have been adding support for features and the new additions to the standard library, and other compilers have as well.

- http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport
- http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html
- [Compiler support for upcoming C++0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980573/compiler-support-for-upcoming-c0x)
- http://www.aristeia.com/C++0x/C++0xFeatureAvailability.htm
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No.  It isn't finished yet.  They are aiming for the end of 2011.

Some portions of it have been released early in something called TR-1 (Technical Report 1) which are mostly library extensions.  Compilers do support this today including Microsoft's latest Visual Studio.