# C++0x IDE support with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++

What IDE has a better support for the new C++0x features in g++?

I know you can use the editor as is and compile the code using -std=c++0x, but I would want the new features do not be marked as errors by the IDE (auto, range-based loop, variadic templates, etc.).

Comment: lambdas, typed enums, auto; none seem to work so far on netbeans 7

Comment: i think not specifying platform is intentional (or should be)

Comment: @Tomalak, yes its duplicate, but that question is from 2009, hopefully things have changed for c++0x and ide in two years - which brings the topic; shouldn't SO support merging of questions? it seems so, so maybe the question should be merged rather than marking it as duplicate (which would effectively close it)

Comment: @lurscher: Yes. The ideal result of closing this as a dupe is that the two can be merged.

Comment: @lurscher: Right, so we'll just list the answer for every possible platform, shall we?!

Comment: i would hope merging is a rather different operation from closing as dupe - in other case, closing it as dupe would be a bad idea

Comment: @lurscher: Why? Step 1: closed as duplicate. Step 2: duplicate merged into original.

Comment: Since the two questions don't have the same answer, they are not duplicates.  Unless you know of a good way to integrate G++ with Visual Studio, which is the accepted answer to the other question.

Comment: @stonemetal: That is incorrect. That is not how duplicates are defined in SO.

Comment: @0A0D Really? According to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/when-is-a-duplicate-question-not-a-duplicate and all the other linked questions about Dups seem to agree that dups are defined by the answers they produce rather than the questions asked.

Comment: @stonemetal: In one of the referenced questions, @TheTXI states : "I would imagine that when a question is asking the same thing (and likely to get the exact same answer), then it should be classified as a dupe." This question is likely to get the same answer as the provided duplicate link and is essentially the same exact question.

Comment: @0A0D: I know VisualStudio 2010 IDE has good support for all the C++0x features that Visual C++ 10 implements (quite poor support actually if comparing it against g++ 4.6, for example). So, as my question is heavily related to g++, I do not think my question is duplicated.

Comment: @ebascomp: Ok, then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/980573/compiler-support-for-upcoming-c0x and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657511/c-compiler-that-supports-c0x-features

Comment: @0A0D: Those are both about compilers, not IDEs.

Comment: @Stonemetal: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95799/closing-as-duplicate-when-the-answers-are-duplicates <-- Dupes are NOT defined by answers.

Comment: @Tomalak, not a dupe. The other one was about only windows IDEs. They only overlap.

Answer (score 2):

Here is [the Eclipse CDT bug tracking support for the c++0x features added in g++ 4.6](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327297).

So far CDT supports the features in g++ 4.5 (that includes type inference with auto, decltype and trailing return types, variadic templates, lambdas, rvalue refs) plus range-based for and forward declaration of enums. The parser tweaks were done a while ago, and judging by the milestones, the latest Eclipse release (Indigo) includes them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) has had support for a while but I do not know to what extent.

Comment: Though it is working good, I do not know if the IDE has good support for C++0x or simply it does not have support for parsing my code while editing it. Anyway, it is nice and I will give it a try :) :) Thanks!

Comment: The version I'm currently using don't understand type inference keywords (auto, decltype) , not for coloring nor type detection. I'm using gcc4.5 with it.

Comment: Down vote because the last time i check the Code::Blocks do not support.

Comment: @Mike: please see (http://hello-cpp0x.blogspot.com/2011/05/enable-c0x-support-in-gcc.html)